# Слетел перевод для правки метки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и язык кода "default" не переведён.

Comment: Строки такой нет. [Попросил](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344268/260198) добавить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не было этой строки в Переводчике (traducir). [Попросил](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344268/260198) добавить.

Сейчас [появилась](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14225). Добавил перевод:

> Отредактировать описание метки

Появится с обновлением движка.

Answer (score 1):

`default` и не должно быть переведено. Это маркер языка для маркдауна, он пишется только на английском.